# I need to read JSON data from a file onto my webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have this JSON array:

```
    var products = [
{
"productID":"1",
"name":"Stark Navy",
"url": "stark.jpg",
"description": "Waterproof, double velcro straps",
"price": "£45.00"
}, 
{
 "productID":"2",
    "name":"Magica Pink",
    "url":"Images/magica.jpg", 
    "description": "Waterproof, pressure sensed lights",
    "price":"£45.00"
},
{
"productID":"3",
    "name":"William Black",
    "url":"Images/william.jpg", 
    "description": "Leather, double velcro straps",
    "price":"£45.00"
}
];
```

and I need to read it onto my webpage when a button/image is clicked. I have tried to build the JS function that will call the products on this list:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $.getJSON('shoppingcart.json', function(data) {
        var output="<div>";

        $.each(data.products, function(i, item) {
            output+="<div id='div" + data.products[i].productID + "'</div>"      +

data.products[i].name + "'>" + 

 "<img src='" + data.products[i].url + "' />" + "<p>" +      data.products[i].description + "</p>" +
 "<p>" + data.products[i].price + "</p>" +


"</div>";
            return ( i !== 3 );

        });

        output+="</div>";
        $("#mainContent").html(output);
  });



$("#geox").click(function(){
    $("#mainContent").fadeIn();
});
```

The button I am clicking has an ID of geox and I want the new data from the JSON file to appear in the div with ID "mainContent".

Just wondering if I'm missing something in this code because it won't read into the webpage.

Okay so here's also the part of the HTML I'm hoping to change when the button is pressed:

```
<button>Geox</button> <button>Converse</button> <button>Startrite</button>     <button>Lea Lelo</button>
<div id="mainContent" class="products">
    <h2>Startrite - Best of the Best</h2>
<section>
 <p>SuperSoft Lily Navy</p>
<img src="images/supersoft%20lily.jpg" id="startrite"/>
<p>Leather, double velcro straps</p>
<p>£39.00</p>
<p>AquaSplash Black</p>
<img src="images/aquasplash.jpg" id="startrite"/>
<p>Leather ankle boot, double velrco straps</p>
<p>£50.00</p>
</section>
<section>
 <p>Cats Whiskers White</p>
<img src="images/cats.jpg" id="startrite"/>
<p>Leather/Patent, single T-bar riptape strap</p>
<p>£38.00</p>
<p>SuperSoft Zac Brown</p>
<img src="images/zac.jpg" id="startrite"/>
<p>Leather, multi-colour riptape single strap</p>
<p>£36.00</p>        
</section>
<section>
<p>Scissors Black</p>
<img src="images/scissors.jpg" id="startrite"/>
<p>Leather school shoes, single riptape strap</p>
<p>£40.00</p>
<p>Hover Black</p>
<img src="images/hover.jpg" id="startrite"/>
<p>Leather school shoes, double velcro straps</p>
<p>£42.00</p>  
</section>        
</div> <!-- End Main Content -->
```

I just want it to change the first 3 images to begin with, then once its working I can change the rest of the data.

Comment: Does the console display any errors?

Comment: That's a javascript file, not a JSON file.

Answer (score 1):

You're returning JavaScript, not JSON.

Remove the 'var products='

Then access it with

```
 $.each(data, function...
```

Comment: also the ; at the end

Comment: So the JSON file should look like this then:

Comment: [
    {
    "productID":"1",
    "name":"Stark Navy",
"url": "stark.jpg",
"description": "Waterproof, double velcro straps",
"price": "£45.00"
    }, 
    {
     "productID":"2",
        "name":"Magica Pink",
        "url":"Images/magica.jpg", 
        "description": "Waterproof, pressure sensed lights",
        "price":"£45.00"
    },
    {
    "productID":"3",
        "name":"William Black",
        "url":"Images/william.jpg", 
        "description": "Leather, double velcro straps",
        "price":"£45.00"
    }
]

Comment: Should I be using that $.each(data, function... instead of $(document).ready(function(){?

Comment: No, that would be in place of the '$.each(data.products, function...' bit

Comment: You will be accessing the array with 'data' instead of 'data.products'

Answer (score 0):

By the way your javascript code has some errors also. 
This is a better version:

```
    <script>


    $(document).ready(function(){

    $.getJSON("shoppingcart.json", function(data) {
        var output="<div>";

        $.each(data.products, function(i, item) {

            output+="<div id='div" + data.products[i].productID + "' name='"  +
            data.products[i].name + "'>" + 
            "<img src='" + data.products[i].url + "' />" + "<p>" +      data.products[i].description + "</p>" +
            "<p>" + data.products[i].price + "</p>" +
            "</div>";
            return ( i !== 3 );

        });

        output+="</div>";
        $("#mainContent").html(output);
    }, function(error){console.log("ERROR");});
    });



    $("#geox").click(function(){
        $("#mainContent").fadeIn();
    });


    </script>
```

You have in the JSON some URLs with the "images\" prefix and some others without it.

```
{
"products": [
{
"productID":"1",
"name":"Stark Navy",
"url": "stark.jpg",
"description": "Waterproof, double velcro straps",
"price": "£45.00"
}, 
{
 "productID":"2",
    "name":"Magica Pink",
    "url":"Images/magica.jpg", 
    "description": "Waterproof, pressure sensed lights",
    "price":"£45.00"
},
{
"productID":"3",
    "name":"William Black",
    "url":"Images/william.jpg", 
    "description": "Leather, double velcro straps",
    "price":"£45.00"
}]
}
```

Also, make sure you have the scripting code is AFTER the HTML code, otherwise this line wont work "$("#geox")...."

And one final thing, the images are changed INMEDIATELY because your "mainContent" element is always visible.

Comment: Ok I've changed my file.. but it still won't read into the webpage. Could it be a problem with the function?

Comment: Please, remove the ";" at the end. I just tried your code and my example and that is what was failing.

Comment: Please, make also sure that your json file is being retrieved to the client

Comment: Ok so remove the ";" from the JSON file? or the Javascript?

Comment: My new answer (I edited it a couple of days ago) has all the recommended changes. Please, read the text carefully to understand my suggestions. Take a look at the new JavaScript code I am proposing, put the JavaScript  at the end of your document, this is, right before the closing </body> tag. Also, copy the new JSON code I posted, the ";" was removed from there already.